# Tcp-NetConnection is Failing with Error "Cannot convert value to type System.String"

Tags: powershell

I am using the below Code to get the content and test it using TCP-netconnection in Powershell. But, I am getting an Error like below.

```
Test-NetConnection : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'ComputerName'. Cannot convert value to type System.String. At line:2 char:34
+ Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $Name -Port 445
+                                  ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-NetConnection], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Test-NetConnection
```

Below is script command that I have used.

```
$Name = Get-Content "C:\Users\vishnuvardhan.chapal\Documents\Test File.txt"
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $Name -Port 445
```

Does anyone have an idea on, "How to Convert read data into a string"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $name variable potentially has an array of computer names stored in it. The computername parameter only accepts one string. You will need to loop through your computer names like the following:

```
$Name = Get-Content "C:\Users\vishnuvardhan.chapal\Documents\Test File.txt"
$name | foreach-object {test-netconnection -computername $_ -port 445}
```

Your test file.txt file needs to have only computer names in it. They need to be one computer name per line format.

Comment: from the docs, it seems that cmdlet will accept pipeline input directly. have you tried that? i can't test it since it doesn't exist on win7ps5.1 ... [*sigh ...*]